# App Inventor app does not take answers in divisions

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to make an app that has the four basic mathematical operations. Addition, subtraction, multiplication and division.

Each operation has a series of exercises and for each correct exercise, assign a point in a score counter.

I clarify that both, the exercises and the answers are selected at random. They are not questions and answers stored in a list.

Everything is ready and finished, but I have a problem with the division and it is as follows.

If, for example, the result of the division has exactly two decimals, the score counter takes as correct the answer that is selected. But if the result of the division has more than two decimals, the score counter does not take the answer as correct.

Example:

20/8 = 1.25 No more decimals, then the score counter takes it as the correct answer

9/7 = 1.28571428571 This answer has many decimals, then the score counter does not take it as the correct answer

The problem is not in rounding up the figures or in formatting the number of decimals. The problem is that for some reason, answers with more than two decimal numbers are not taken as correct.

Not matter if I round the result to a integer or if I set only a 2 decimals for each result, for some reason, the score counter do not show the result as correct.

For example, if I take the division 9/7 = 1.28571428571 and I set only 2 decimals for the result, leaving it as 1.28, the score counter do not take this result as a correct result.

Even if I round the result to 1, occur the same problem.

How can this be fixed?

Many thanks to anyone who can help me find a solution.

P.S.: I'm not a programmer I'm just an amateur and nothing else, that just starts, so I appreciate, please, answers for a layman like me. Thanks in advance.

[Here are the blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/808sb.jpg)
[image: Here are the blocks]

Comment: is there really someone, who likes to debug your complete project? If yes: fine, if not, see my answer to your question in the Thunkable forum here https://community.thunkable.com/t/can-anybody-help-me-please/52053/9?u=taifun

Comment: Thanks. I have already answered your comment on thunkable.